# How can I access my web app JavaScript methods in android application using WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` for my Webpage. Now how can I call `JS` methods for that web page and update in the `UI`. For example I have this method for getting number of slides.

> $.Docs.get.fileCount()

How can I call this `JS` method from android and update the slides count in the `UI`.?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
webWiew.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('userid').value ='"+userName+"'};");
```